# How to write fluent validation rules inside IValidateOptions using FluentValidation?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-5, fluentvalidation

For my .Net 5 workerservice app I want to validate options by implementing the `IValidateOptions` interface but don't want to write my own error messages. That's why I want to make use of the package **FluentValidation.AspNetCore**.

Given the model

```
namespace App.Models
{
    public class MyOptions
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I added validation rules

```
namespace App.ModelValidators
{
    public class MyOptionsValidator : AbstractValidator<MyOptions>
    {
        public MyOptionsValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(model => model.Text).NotEmpty();
        }
    }
}
```

Next I'm using this validator inside the validation

```
namespace App.OptionsValidators
{
    public class MyOptionsValidator : IValidateOptions<MyOptions>
    {
        private readonly IValidator<MyOptions> _validator;
        
        public MyOptionsValidator(IValidator<MyOptions> validator)
        {
            _validator = validator;
        }
        
        public ValidateOptionsResult Validate(string name, MyOptions options)
        {
            var validationResult = _validator.Validate(options);

            if (validationResult.IsValid)
            {
                return ValidateOptionsResult.Success;
            }
            
            return ValidateOptionsResult.Fail(validationResult.Errors.Select(validationFailure => validationFailure.ErrorMessage));
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly I setup the DI container

```
services.AddTransient<IValidator<MyOptions>, ModelValidators.MyOptionsValidator>();
services.AddSingleton<IValidateOptions<MyOptions>, OptionsValidators.MyOptionsValidator>();
services.Configure<MyOptions>(configuration.GetSection("My"));
```

I would like to know if this can be simplified?

Maybe I can just implement the `IValidateOptions` interface, avoid the `AbstractValidator` and write fluent rules inside the `.Validate()` method?

**Sample code what I want to achieve**

```
namespace App.OptionsValidators
{
    public class MyOptionsValidator : IValidateOptions<MyOptions>
    {
        public ValidateOptionsResult Validate(string name, MyOptions options)
        {
            var validationResult = options.Text.Should.Not.Be.Empty();

            if (validationResult.IsValid)
            {
                return ValidateOptionsResult.Success;
            }
            
            return ValidateOptionsResult.Fail(validationResult.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

so I don't need the `AbstractValidator<MyOptions>` anymore.

---

**My first approach I'm not sure about**

Instead of using FluentValidation I'm using DataAnnotations.

- I added the `[Required]` attribute to the `Text` property
- I completely removed the class `MyOptionsValidator : AbstractValidator<MyOptions>`
- I only register this in the DI setup

.

```
services.AddSingleton<IValidateOptions<MyOptions>, OptionsValidators.MyOptionsValidator>();
services.Configure<MyOptions>(configuration.GetSection("My"));
```

Inside `MyOptionsValidator` I validate the options like so

```
    public ValidateOptionsResult Validate(string name, MyOptions options)
    {
        var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        
        if (!Validator.TryValidateObject(options, new ValidationContext(options), validationResults, true))
        {
            return ValidateOptionsResult.Fail(validationResults.Select(validationResult => validationResult.ErrorMessage));
        }

        return ValidateOptionsResult.Success;
    }
```

but maybe there are still better ways :)

Comment: Of course, you can do, but it will destroy the purpose: **"don't want to write my own error messages"**, not just messages though, entire validation

Comment: @Eldar may I ask how you would solve this?

Comment: I would stick with your current implementation. Removing a validator will give you a burden of validation of the model and creating the validation result.

Comment: @Eldar what do you think about my approach? This would eliminate some things

Comment: I'm still with the first approach. You removed a validator instead now you are using another framework to validate. Dancing with 2 validation frameworks might get troublesome as the application gets more complex.

Comment: wait, now I'm just using the "default" framework and not FluentValidation anymore

Comment: If you say you are not using FluentValidation in other parts of your application then it's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a strong preference to utilise the same approach for validation across the stack, and in my case this is via FluentValidation. The following would be my approach.

Create a new base validator for your options/settings validators:

```
public abstract class AbstractOptionsValidator<T> : AbstractValidator<T>, IValidateOptions<T>
    where T : class
{
    public virtual ValidateOptionsResult Validate(string name, T options)
    {
        var validateResult = this.Validate(options);
        return validateResult.IsValid ? ValidateOptionsResult.Success : ValidateOptionsResult.Fail(validateResult.Errors.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));
    }
}
```

This extends the FluentValidation `AbstractValidator<T>` to support `IValidateOptions<T>`. You've now got a base that you can use for all of your options/settings validators. For the following settings:

```
public class FooSettings
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

you end up with a typical validator:

```
public class FooSettingsValidator : AbstractOptionsValidator<FooSettings>, IFooSettingsValidator
{
    public FooSettingsValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Bar).NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

Let the DI container know about it:

```
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IValidateOptions<FooSettings>, FooSettingsValidator>();
```

If there is nothing built in to do the above, I'd look to Scrutor to turn this into an automatic process.

All of the above affords me all of the benefits of using FluentValidation, whilst utilising the first class options validation support that Microsoft has provided for us.

LINQPad working example:

[image]

[image]

```
using static FluentAssertions.FluentActions;

void Main()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    var validator = new FooSettingsValidator();
    validator.Validate(fixture.Build<FooSettings>().Without(x => x.Bar).Create()).Errors.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage).Should().BeEquivalentTo(new string[] { "'Bar' must not be empty." });
    validator.Validate(fixture.Build<FooSettings>().Create()).Errors.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage).Should().BeEquivalentTo(new string[] { });

    using (var scope = ServiceProvider.Create(bar: null).CreateScope())
    {
        Invoking(() => scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsSnapshot<FooSettings>>().Value).Should().Throw<OptionsValidationException>();
    }

    using (var scope = ServiceProvider.Create(bar: "asdf").CreateScope())
    {
        scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsSnapshot<FooSettings>>().Value.Bar.Should().Be("asdf");
    }
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here
public class FooSettings
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public interface IFooSettingsValidator : IValidator { }

public class FooSettingsValidator : AbstractOptionsValidator<FooSettings>, IFooSettingsValidator
{
    public FooSettingsValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Bar).NotEmpty();
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractOptionsValidator<T> : AbstractValidator<T>, IValidateOptions<T>
    where T : class
{
    public virtual ValidateOptionsResult Validate(string name, T options)
    {
        var validateResult = this.Validate(options);
        return validateResult.IsValid ? ValidateOptionsResult.Success : ValidateOptionsResult.Fail(validateResult.Errors.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));
    }
}

public class ServiceProvider
{
    public static IServiceProvider Create(string bar)
    {
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .AddInMemoryCollection(
                        new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Foo:Bar", bar) })
                    .Build();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config);
        serviceCollection.AddOptions();
        //serviceCollection.Configure<FooSettings>(config.GetSection("Foo"));
        serviceCollection.AddOptions<FooSettings>()
                            .Bind(config.GetSection("Foo"));

        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IValidateOptions<FooSettings>, FooSettingsValidator>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IFooSettingsValidator, FooSettingsValidator>();

        return serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found below code in this article https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2020/april/validate-configurations-with-fluentvalidation-in-aspnet-core/

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  
{  
    services.Configure<EndpointsConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(EndpointsConfiguration)));  
    services.AddSingleton<AbstractValidator<EndpointsConfiguration>, EndpointsConfigurationValidator>();  
  
    services.AddSingleton<EndpointsConfiguration>(container =>  
    {  
        var config = container.GetService<IOptions<EndpointsConfiguration>>().Value;  
        var validator = container.GetService<AbstractValidator<EndpointsConfiguration>>();  
        validator.Validate(config);  
        return config;  
    });  
  
    services.AddControllers();  
}
```

This way you can have all you validation in implementation of `AbstractValidator` and it will be simpler than you current implementation. Using this you don't need to implement `IOptionsValidator` I guess. The article has a good explanation so refer to get more insights.

Comment: thanks. But what if `.Validate()` has some errors? I don't know much about the default behaviour

Comment: The same article says this,
`Once application is started, validation is triggered on the pipeline initialization and ValidationException is thrown from validation rule(in case validation rule fails) configured in EndpointsConfigurationValidator class.`

Answer (score 0):

I can simplify using the *System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations*

```
 public class MyOptions
 {
      [Required]
      public string Text { get; set; }
 }
```

then you can customize your BadRequest via the pipeline

```
 services.AddControllers()
         .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(opts =>
         {
               opts.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
               {
                   var problemDetails = new ViolationProblemDetails()
                   {
                         Instance = context.HttpContext.Request.Path,
                         Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest,
                         Detail = "Please refer to the errors property for additional details."
                    };

                    problemDetails.Violations = new List<Violation>();

                    foreach (var modelState in context.ModelState)
                    {
                        problemDetails.Violations.Add(new Violation()
                        {
                            Field = modelState.Key,
                            Message = string.Join(",",modelState.Value.Errors.Select(a => a.ErrorMessage))
                         });
                        }

                        return new BadRequestObjectResult(problemDetails);
                    };
                })
```

more information
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: 1. I'm sorry but this is not a Web API project,  2. wouldn't it be easier to use `.ValidateDataAnnotations()` instead?